# dropzone.js increment a variable when file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have started to use `dropzone.js` and i have designed this code :

```
$(function() {

   var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone",{ url: "http://127.0.0.1/" } );

   var index = 0;

   myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
     index = index++;
   });

   myDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file) {     
   });

})
```

The index variable doesn't get incremented. Is there is a way to increment this variable?

Answer (score 0):

> [The "++" increment] operator increments (adds one to) its operand and
>   returns a value. **If used postfix, with operator after operand (for
>   example, x++), then it returns the value before incrementing.** If used
>   prefix with operator before operand (for example, ++x), then it
>   returns the value after incrementing.

[Documentation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B.2B_.28Increment.29)

You are returning the value *before* incrementing, rather than after.

These will work:

```
index=++index;
```

OR

```
index++;
```

OR

```
index=index+1;
```

OR

```
index+=1;
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/ec4Uj/3/